# Binding to several Prperties

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0, binding

How do bind to more than one property in WPF?
I know that you can use the `ItemStringFormat="{0} my hard coded string"` to describe a string value but I am interested in something like this `ItemStringFormat="{0} ({1})"` where item zero is a property and item one is a property in the bound class.

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
   public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

`<ComboBox Margin="5,0" Name="Currency" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Code"/>`

This will give me a list with all the currency descriptions but what i want is something like this
"US Dollar (USD)"
where is "US Dollar" is the property Description and "USD" is the prorpety Code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to convert from multiple sources into a single target property (ie: Text).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct and for the sake of documentation i will provide that solution here using the example above.

`<ComboBox Margin="5,0" Name="CurrentCurrency" ItemsSource="{Binding}">`
`<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>`
`<DataTemplate>`
`<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">`
`<TextBlock.Text>`
`<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">`
`<Binding Path="Description" />`
`<Binding Path="Code" />`
`</MultiBinding>`
`</TextBlock.Text>`
`</TextBlock>`
`</DataTemplate>`
`</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>`
`</ComboBox>`